# MoveFile Внутренняя реализация и отслеживание прогресса

Tags: c++, winapi

Каким образом WINAPI функция `MoveFile` выполняет перемещение файлов или папок: просто меняет информацию о расположении файлов в FAT или же выполняет копирование данных и удаление оригинальных файлов с диска (иными словами вызывается `CopyFile` и `DeleteFile`)? Каким образом можно отследить прогресс операции? Есть WINAPI функция [MoveFileTransacted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefiletransacteda), однако в документации настоятельно рекомендуется не использовать её, но альтернатив конкретно под эту задачу я не нашёл.

Comment: А если задуматься? :) Например, если это на одном диске и **можно** просто выполнить переименование, или на разных и просто переименовать **нельзя**? Или обязательно надо только вот так, и никак иначе?...

Comment: Если происходит перемещение на другой диск, то очевидно, что это копирование и затем удаление. Я имел ввиду ситуацию с перемещением в переделах одного диска.

Comment: Даже в пределах одного диска это может быть монтирование другого диска как папки... Вариантов много. Кстати, хотите проверить? Сравните время перемещения файла в несколько гигабайт.

Comment: То есть ответ на первый вопрос - просто переименовывание файлов, если этого достаточно.

Comment: Используйте `IFileOperation` для получения прогресса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если происходит перемещение на другой диск, то очевидно, что это копирование и затем удаление. Я имел ввиду ситуацию с перемещением в пределах одного диска.

Как-раз недавно пришлось исследовать структуры NTFS, и написал для этого спец.утилиту. Из стороннего софта использовал WinHex, который в удобном виде отображает все метафайлы, типа **$MFT** и прочие. В зарегистрированной его версии можно звать даже шаблоны структур **$BOOT** и **"FILE_RECORD"** - очень удобно. Но для начала небольшой ликбез для начинающих.

Каждый файл на диске NTFS описывается структурой **"FILE_RECORD"** *(паспорт файла)* - сколько файлов на диске, столько и записей **Record** *(папка тоже считается файлом)*. Размер одной записи указывается в структуре "$BOOT", найти которую можно в секторе(0) каждого из разделов/томов. В дефолте, размер сектора 512-байт, кластера 4096 *(8 секторов)*, а размер одной записи Record = 2 сектора, или 1КБ.

Для хранения всех записей Record используется таблица **$MFT** - Master File Table. У каждого раздела диска своя $MFT. Указатель на неё в кластерах прописывается в структуре $BOOT раздела. Отдельная запись "FILE_RECORD" может иметь макс.16 различных свойств, которые [в доках числятся](https://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf) как **"ATTRIBUTE"** *(не путать с файловыми атрибутами ОС типа "Hidden" и прочие)*.

Таким образом, в строках таблицы $MFT указывается имя файла *(сигнатура "FILE" в начале сектора)*, а в 16-ти её столбцах - атрибуты. Как-правило, у записей Record всего 3..6 атрибута, из возможных 16-ти. Так выглядит картина в общих чертах.

Теперь к вопросу о перемещении файлов в пределах своего и соседнего раздела. Для этого, достаточно прочитать Record интересующего файла, и сравнить его до и после перемещения. В своём коде я вывожу на консоль сл.детали о записи Record:

1. Основная структура **"FILE_RECORD"** начинается с порядкового **номера записи** в глобальной $MFT. Флаг **"Record status"** - это битовая маска: (0)запись недействительна и её можно использовать повторно, т.е. файл удалён; (1)активная запись, (2)запись описывает папку. Если папка на диске активна, то флаг принимает значение(3), если удалена(2). Для файлов он всегда равен 1 или 0.
2. Поле с номером **"Update sequency"** позволяет отыскивать Record'ы одной записи, когда они размазаны по всему диску, т.е. фрагментированны. Это значение прошивается в самый конец сектора, и является уникальным.
3. В атрибуте записи **"STANDART"** нас интересует поле **"ChangeTime"** - это время последнего изменения данной Record в таблице $MFT. NTFS изменяет поле, например, при переименовании файла. В поле **"Security"** хранятся такие атрибуты безопасности файла, как DACL/SACL и прочие.
4. Атрибут **"FILE_NAME"** уже более информативен. Здесь имеется ссылка на Record родителя **"Parent"**. Если запись описывает файл *(см.пункт 1)*, то родителем всегда будет каталог верхнего уровня и т.д., пока не упрёмся в корневой дир раздела. Флаг резидента показывает, где находится текущая запись - в таблице $MFT =1, или за её пределами =0. Далее перечисляются знакомые нам атрибуты ОС типа "Скрытый, Системный, Архивный" и т.п. Функция Win `GetFileAttribute()` для папок возвращает значение(10h), а здесь это `1000.0000h`.

Теперь что мы видим на скрине ниже?
Когда файл перемещается в пределах своего раздела, то в оригинальном Record просто меняется ссылка на родителя "Parent", и сразу фиксируется время изменения данной записи. То-есть сам файл "lang_ru.ini" фактически остался на своём месте!

Но когда файл перемещается на другой том, то это реальное копирование всех данных. При этом оригинальная информация не стирается физически с диска, а лишь в основной структуре "FILE_RECORD" статус сбрасывается в нуль **"Deleted"**. Обратите внимание, что это одна и та-же запись с номером `#0000100916`. Таким образом, криминалисты легко могут обнаружить все удалённые файлы, если их секторы не затёрли новые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]